# Rust, SeaORM and database session problem

Tags: postgresql, rust

I'm developing a REST server application using Rust, Axum, and SeaORM, accessing PostgreSQL.

The database is configured with a multi-tenant feature, using a session configuration to grant access to records.

The issue lies in SeaORM. How do I assign the session property of the connection and perform queries?

The database is configured as per the tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/saas-multitenant-managed-postgresql/rls.html

To access information, it is necessary, during session initialization, to execute:

SET app.tenant = 1;

The problem is that SeaORM is not maintaining the same session, and when I look for other information, it always returns empty.

SELECT * FROM tickets;

How do I proceed to maintain the database session?

I create a extractor to the connection and set the session variable each time. But, in the handle, the connection has no session aplied.

Answer (score 0):

I took a step forward. If I start a transaction, I can maintain the session between some database operations.

`let txn = db.begin().await?;`